# getting ajax to update database via php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm using AJAX for the first time to send a simple query to my mysql database which will add a "product". However it doesn't seem to send the request to my database.
I have 3 files addProduct.php which is where the form is based, test.js which is the javascript/ajax for the request and my addProductTodatabase which is where the query is.

(just in cased i've messed up the files structure)

- addProduct.php is at F:\xampp\htdocs\cw test.js is at
- test.js is at F:\xampp\htdocs\cw\javaScript
- addProductTodatabase.php is at  F:\xampp\htdocs\cw\mysql

the form uses this code..

```
<form name ="myForm" class = "hidden" id = "addProduct">
            <h2 class = "under"> Next step: </h2>
            <h4> Fill in the following information </h4>
            <label class = "under" > Product Name <input type="text" name="ProductName" id = "productName"> </label>
            <label class = "under" > Product category <input type="text" name="ProductCategory" id = "productCat"> </label>
            <label class = "under" > Suitable age plus  <input type="text" name="ProductAge" id = "productAge"> </label>
            <label class = "under" >Add a Product discrition </label>
            <textarea  id = "productArea" name ="ProductDis" rows="15" cols="100"></textArea>
            <label class = "under" > Product Price <input type="text" name="ProductPrice" id = "productPrice"> </label>
            <label class = "under" > Number available  <input type="text" name="ProductInStock" id = "productAvailable"> </label>
            <label class = "under" > Image location <input type ="file" name= "ImageLocation" id= "imageLocation"> </label>         
            <input type ="button" onclick = "queryTest()" value = "Submit to database">
            </form> 

            <div id = "loading">this should update </div>
```

test.js uses this code..

```
function queryTest()
{

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
     document.getElementById('loading').innerHTML = "Please wait..."; 
    //document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  //document.getElementById('loading').innerHTML = "Please wait..."; 
  // gets the variables and passes it onto the php page in the url bar
  var productName = document.getElementById('productName').value;
  var productCat = document.getElementById('productCat').value;
  var productAge = document.getElementById('productAge').value;
  var productDis = document.getElementById('productArea').value;
  var productPrice = document.getElementById('productPrice').value;
  var productStock = document.getElementById('productAvailable').value;
  var productImage = document.getElementById('imageLocation').value;
  var queryString = "?ProductName=" + productName + "&ProductCategory=" +  productCat;
  queryString += "&ProductAge=" + productAge + "&ProductDis=" + productDis;
  queryString += "&ProductPrice=" + productPrice + "&ProductInStock=" + productStock;
  queryString += "&ImageLocation=" + productImage;

xmlhttp.open("GET","../mysql/addProductTodatabase.php" + queryString,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);

}
```

and addProductToDatabase uses this...

```
<?php

    include "databaseLogIn.php";

//get variables from page before  
    $ProductName = $_GET["ProductName"];  
    $ProductCategory = $_GET["ProductCategory"]; 
    $ProductAge = $_GET["ProductAge"];
    $ProductDis = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["ProductDis"]); 
    $ProductPrice = $_GET["ProductPrice"];
    $ProductInStock = $_GET["ProductInStock"];
    include "/imageHander/imagePointerDownloader.php";

//adds to table
    $sql ="INSERT INTO Product ( ProductName, ProductCategory, SuitableAge, ProductDiscription, ProductPrice, ProductAvailable) 
    VALUES ('$ProductName','$ProductCategory','$ProductAge','$ProductDis','$ProductPrice','$ProductInStock')"; 
    mysql_query($sql,$con);

// gets the product id
    $query="SELECT * FROM Product"; 
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $ItemID=mysql_numrows($result);

    $PictureCaption = "this is a picture";
// adds picture caption
//adds a image to the table related to the product  
    $sql="INSERT INTO ProductPictures (ItemID, PictureCaption, ImagePointer)
        VALUES ('$ItemID', '$PictureCaption', '$newFile')";
//echo $sql;

    mysql_query($sql,$con)


    mysql_close($con)
  ?>
```

Any help is welcomed, thank you for reading.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: ^ I will look into this thank you (I swear my university lectures are soo outdated), however I still need help with this problem before I move on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ***addProductTodatabase.php*** :

```
<?php

include "databaseLogIn.php";

//get variables from page before  
    $ProductName = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["ProductName"],$con);  
    $ProductCategory = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["ProductCategory"],$con); 
    $ProductAge = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["ProductAge"],$con); 
    $ProductDis = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["ProductDis"],$con); 
    $ProductPrice = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["ProductPrice"],$con); 
    $ProductInStock = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["ProductInStock"],$con); 

// Check if this is the right path - who knows?
    include "./imageHander/imagePointerDownloader.php";

//adds to table
    $sql ="INSERT INTO Product ( ProductName, ProductCategory, SuitableAge, ProductDiscription, ProductPrice, ProductAvailable) 
    VALUES ('$ProductName','$ProductCategory','$ProductAge','$ProductDis','$ProductPrice','$ProductInStock')"; 
    mysql_query($sql,$con);

// gets the product id
    $query="SELECT * FROM Product"; 
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $ItemID=mysql_numrows($result);

// adds picture caption    
    $PictureCaption = "this is a picture";

//adds a image to the table related to the product  
    $sql="INSERT INTO ProductPictures (ItemID, PictureCaption, ImagePointer)
        VALUES ('$ItemID', '$PictureCaption', '$newFile')";

//echo $sql;

// ---
// You were missing a semicolon here.
// ---
    mysql_query($sql,$con);

// ---    
// You were missing a semicolon also here.    
// ---
    mysql_close($con);

?>
```

And your ***test.js*** had a wrong URL to *addProductTodatabase.php*. It should be:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","./mysql/addProductTodatabase.php" + queryString,true);
```

The path is **relative to the html/php file** the script is included in.

Plus what j0k said is right. You ***should*** use MySQLi. MySQL is deprecated.